# OS X Boot Loader

Tags: macos, multi-boot

I have both Vista 7 HP 64-bit and SL 10.6 installed on my mac. I need a lilo like Boot Loader prompting me to make a selection from these two os(es). I require the boot loader be stylish and simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[rEFit](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) may be an option.

Answer (score 2):

That functionality's built in when you dual boot using Boot Camp. Hold down the Option key on the keyboard while booting/rebooting the machine (right after the start up chime). You'll be presented with a screen showing your bootable volumes, just pick one and go. Easy peasie.

No 3rd party bootloader needed.